# Oil viscosity question

Tags: small-engine, briggs-stratton

I recently made the mistake of over-filling my ride on lawn mower/Briggs & Strattan motor. Damage to the motor is done now and it's blowing heaps of smoke and fowling the spark plug. Question: Can I use a thicker oil? my thoughts are that it might burn less oil?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Have you tried just draining the oil and putting the right amount in? It's doubtful you truly damaged your engine. After draining you may see some residual smoke, but it should go away rather quickly.

Comment: I didn't do that as I was in a hurry to beat the rain, I kept mowing with the smoke for a couple of hours. when I checked the oil after that it was almost depleted so I  just topped it up.